# What is the significance of limit of a function not existing?

Tags: calculus, limits

If limit of a function exists, we can infer the value which the function is approaching. If limit value equals the value of the function at that point, then it is continuous at that point. But my doubt is what can we infer if limit itself does not exist?

Comment: In the case of a jump, the function approaches different values dependent whether we approach from the left or from the right. If we have a pole, the function diverges to $\pm \infty$, so does not approach a particular value.

Comment: @Peter This doesn't exhaust the possible behaviors.  For example, the function could oscillate like $\sin{1\over x}$ near $0,$ and there are functions that behave a lot worse.  There isn't anything you can infer except that the function doesn't approach a single finite value.

Comment: @saulspatz I did not claim that I covered all cases, there are almost always "pathological" cases.

Comment: So, Can I conclude that sometimes there is a pole at a point where limit doesn’t exist and sometimes there isn’t?

Comment: @user35122 This conclusion is definitely valid. For the existence of a limit, it is required that the limit from the left and from the right coincide. In the case of a jump, this is not satisfied.

Comment: For what it's worth, there are thousands of papers on this topic (in complex analysis, differential equations, Sobolev spaces, harmonic analysis, etc. --- see [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22cluster+sets%22+%22boundary%22) for one of many possible google searches), and two books I can think of right now on this topic (both restricted to the perspective of complex analysis) are [**The Theory of Cluster Sets**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0521046955) by Collingwood/Lohwater and [**Cluster Sets**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/3540025162) by Noshiro.

Comment: Re: The term "pole". The usual meaning is that $x_0$ is a pole of the function $f$ iff $f$ is discontinuous at $x_0$ and $\lim_{x\to x_0}(x-x_0)^nf(x)$ exists for some $n\in \Bbb Z^+$. E.g. if $f(x)=1/x$ for $x\ne 0=x_0$.... If $f(x)=2^{(1/x)}$ for $x\ne 0$ then $f$ is discontinuous at $x_0=0$ but  $0$ is not a pole of $f$

Answer (score 2):

Even when a limit does not exist, nonetheless a "limit set" always exists.

I'll describe this briefly with two assumptions: $f(x)$ has domain $\mathbb R$; and there is a bound $|f(x)| \le B$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$, which lets me simply things by ignoring $+\infty$ and $-\infty$ as elements of the limit set.

The *limit set* of $f(x)$ as $x \to a$ is the set of all $L \in \mathbb R$ such that for every $\epsilon > 0$ and every $\delta > 0$ there exists $x \in (a-\delta,a+\delta)$ such that $f(x) \in (L-\epsilon,L+\epsilon)$. This is equivalent to saying that there exists a sequence $x_i$ converging to $a$ such that the sequence $f(x_i)$ converges to $L$. (One can also broaden the definition to allow $-\infty$ and $+\infty$ to be in the limit set, but to simplify matters I am ignoring that).

It is a consequence of the [Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolzano%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem), combined with the assumption that $f(x)$ is bounded, that the limit set of $f(x)$ as $x$ approaches $a$ is always nonempty. Furthermore, the limit exists if and only if the limit set consists of a single real number, that number being the value of the limit itself.

Everyone's favorite example, mentioned in the comment of @saulspatz, is $\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ as $x \to 0$ (with some artificial value assigned at $x=0$ itself). The limit set is $[-1,+1]$.

Comment: For a unit step function {u(x)}, limit does not exist at x=0. But as you say there always exists a limit set, is it {0,1} for this function at x= 0 ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by a unit step function.

Comment: F(x) = 1 ; x > 0. And F(x) = 0 ; x < 0. ( https://www.intmath.com/laplace-transformation/1a-unit-step-functions-definition.php )

Comment: Then yes, $\{0,1\}$ is indeed the limit set as $x \to 0$.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that we are talking about real-valued functions on some interval of $\mathrm R.$

If the limit of such a function $f$ does not exist at some point $a$ in the interval on which $f$ is defined, then there are two broad possibilities: either the function is still well-behaved in the sense that  the limit is unambiguously infinite (i.e., either $+\infty$ or $-\infty$). An example of such a function is the one defined on $\mathrm R - \{0\}$ by $1/x^2$ and has some real value $v$ at $x=0.$ The other possibility is that $f$ is more unpredictable than the type in the first case; there are many ways this could happen -- the limit may be infinite, but in different directions, at $a,$ or no limit even exists (perhaps $f$ is oscillates infinitely often at $a$) and other possibilities. It should be something enjoyable to investigate these more by yourself.